# matchExpressions not working in setbased selectors ins Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to used set based selectors for replica set in kubernetes. I am not able to use match expressions for setting the filter condition.

Replica set yaml file.

```
# ngnix-replication-set.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
    name: nginx-rs
    # label not required for RC unless it's being referred to somewhere else.
spec:
    replicas: 3
    selector: # set based selector, can be used to select multiple options in single selection
         matchLabels :
            app : nginx
        ** matchExpressions :   # match expressions are not working  
         -{key:environment,operator:In,values:[dev]}
         -{key: tier, operator: NotIn, values: [frontend,backend]}  **
    template :
        metadata:
            name: nginx-pod
            labels:
                app: nginx  #this spec is used in selector
                tier: server
                environment : dev
        spec:
            containers:
            -   name: nginx-container
                image : nginx
                ports:
                -   containerPort: 80
```

Error:

> ngnix-replication-set.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(ReplicaSet.spec.selector.matchExpressions): invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.LabelSelector.matchExpressions: got "string", expected "array"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: Double check indent under `matchExpressions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements) this seems like a indentation issue. Below should work.

```
    ...
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: nginx
      matchExpressions:  
        - {key: environment, operator: In, values: [dev]}
        - {key: tier, operator: NotIn, values: [frontend,backend]}
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked, if you don't mind, can you say me how you resolved this indentation issue. I'm getting these kind of issue in multiple places, it'd help me solve those.

Comment: Use visual code for editing along with some indentation resolving (YAML, Kubectl-support) packages.